# How to add a button to open a link in a browser grabbed from database - PHP

Tags: php, database

I have started to make a program in PHP and it's mostly finished.
But, now I don't know how to open a link on the browser grabbed from database row.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Show your current code and where you are stuck. Connecting to the db? Quer'ing? Printing?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<center><br><br><form>
<input type="button" value="link10" onclick="window.location.href='echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url10']'" />
</form></center>
```

Is that possible something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
     $location = "";
     $db = mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'databasename');
     $sql = "SELECT link FROM tablename";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $location = $row['link'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['newlink'])) {
         header('Location: ' . $location);
      }
 ?>
<html>
<body>
   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
       <input type="submit" name="newlink" value="open page">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: you can also make the header function a redirect function all the header function does is redirect see more here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp

the $_server['php_self'] just gets the url it is like if it was stackoverflow.com/try.php it will get that URL

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');




$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="publiadd_publix"; // Mysql username 
$password="1a3g7893fsh"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="publiadd_urlrotator"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="url_rotator"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM url_rotator ORDER BY root_name DESC LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Print Title
print '<center>'."All Rotator In Our Network! ".'</center>';
print '<center>'."---------------------------".'</center>';
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<center>'.$rows['id'] . " | " . $rows['root_name'] . " | " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url1'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url2'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url3'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url4'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url5'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url6'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url7'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url8'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url9'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$rows['root_url10'] . " * " .'</center>' ;


// close while loop 
}

// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center><br><br><form>
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/home.php'" />
</form></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: NOTE: mysql is deprecated more people are now using mysqli